# data changes with clock

Tags: vhdl, fpga

i am new in the fpga filed ,
im trying to sample 2 inputs that rises with clock at the same time.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_arith;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
ENTITY hold_threat IS
    PORT  (
            pwr_gt_thresh : IN std_logic;
            clk : IN std_logic;
            reset : IN std_logic;
            hw_seperation_bin_number : in std_logic_vector(12 downto 0);
            fft_raw_index : in std_logic_vector (12 downto 0);
            fft_data_valid : in std_logic;
            threat_exists_buffered_pulse : out std_logic;
            pwr_gt_thresh_out : out std_logic;
            threat_end_index :out std_logic_vector (12 downto 0);
            threat_start_index :out std_logic_vector (12 downto 0)
            );
END hold_threat;


ARCHITECTURE behavoral OF hold_threat IS
    signal s_threat_exists_buffered_pulse   :  std_logic;
    signal s_pwr_gt_thresh_out              :  std_logic;
    signal hw_seperation_bin_number_counter : integer range 0 to 8191;
    signal s_fft_start_index :  std_logic_vector (13 downto 0);
    signal s_fft_end_index :  std_logic_vector (12 downto 0);
    signal s_new_count : std_logic;
    
        begin
            threat_start_index <= s_fft_start_index(12 downto 0);
            threat_end_index <= s_fft_end_index;
            threat_exists_buffered_pulse <= s_threat_exists_buffered_pulse;
            pwr_gt_thresh_out <= s_pwr_gt_thresh_out;
            process(reset, clk)
                begin
                    if reset = '1'  then  
                        hw_seperation_bin_number_counter <= to_integer(unsigned(hw_seperation_bin_number)) -1 ; 
                        s_threat_exists_buffered_pulse <= '0';
                        s_fft_start_index <="11" & X"FFF";
                        s_fft_end_index <= '1' & X"FFF";
                        s_new_count <= '0' ; 
                    elsif rising_edge(clk) then 
                        if(fft_data_valid = '1')  then 
                            if (pwr_gt_thresh = '1' ) then 
                                hw_seperation_bin_number_counter <= to_integer(unsigned(hw_seperation_bin_number)) -1; 
                                s_new_count <='1';
                                s_threat_exists_buffered_pulse <= '1';
                                if(s_fft_start_index(13) = '1' ) then 
                                    s_fft_start_index<= '0'& fft_raw_index; 
                                else 
                                    s_fft_start_index<= s_fft_start_index;
                                end if; 
                            else
                                if( hw_seperation_bin_number_counter = 0 ) and s_new_count ='1'then 
                                    s_threat_exists_buffered_pulse <= '0';
                                    s_fft_end_index<= fft_raw_index;
                                    s_new_count <= '0';                                 
                                elsif (s_new_count ='1') then 
                                    hw_seperation_bin_number_counter <= hw_seperation_bin_number_counter - 1;
                                    s_threat_exists_buffered_pulse <= '1';
                                end if; 
                            end if;
            
                        else -- clock , no data valid 
                        s_threat_exists_buffered_pulse <= s_threat_exists_buffered_pulse;
                            if (s_new_count = '0') then 
                                hw_seperation_bin_number_counter <= to_integer(unsigned(hw_seperation_bin_number)) -1 ; 
                                s_fft_start_index <="11" & X"FFF";
                                s_fft_end_index <= '1' & X"FFF";
                            else
                                hw_seperation_bin_number_counter <= hw_seperation_bin_number_counter;
                                s_fft_start_index <=s_fft_start_index;
                                s_fft_end_index <= s_fft_end_index;
                            end if;
                        end if; 
                    end if;
                end process; 
                


END ARCHITECTURE behavoral;
```

in the simulation the clock ,pwr_gt_thresh ,  fft_data_valid rise together at the same time but the condition

```
elsif rising_edge(clk) then 
                        if(fft_data_valid = '1')  then 
                            if (pwr_gt_thresh = '1' ) then
```

is never true .

if i change the simulation so that the data rise before the clock everything works good

why the data and the clock cannot rise together ?

Comment: How are you generating the data in the testbench? Is it synchronous to the clock or are you using an absolute time delay? absolute times can cause delta races, so I recommend synchronising it to the clock.

Comment: As Tricky mentioned, you should register the signals in the test bench. Just create a synchronous process and output the signals from there.

Answer (score -1):

*Disclaimer: For more complete details you might want to do some research on "setup time" for clocked logic. And while you're at it, keep reading on "hold time".*

In just three sentences:

The signal on a sampled data line needs to fulfill some timing requirements to be "caught" correctly. The time before the clock edge is the setup time. The time the signal has to be stable is the hold time.

---

Something to think about for fun:

You will come across values of real hardware that specify *negative* setup times. Was does this mean?